# Bind view model to content control/presenter

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

on uwp, I want to make a hamburger menu with custom icon in xaml. from the lunch scheduler sample from MS, I try to bind a viewmodel property to a content element in a view  like :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:MenuItem">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ContentControl Content="{x:Bind Icon2}" />
```

where Icon is a property like

```
Icon2 = Application.Current.Resources["BookIcon"],
```

which works and retreive a viewbox containing a canvas

but I got an exception "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Did some know if it's possible like in WPF ??

nb : if i put the canvas directly in the contentcontrol, it works. perhaps the binding does not accept anything else than string

Comment: "but I got an exception"  is not a sufficient problem description. Please be more precise, e.g. tell us what kind of exception you get, what the exception message is, and if there is an inner exception.

Comment: what's an "ihm"? do you have a full, minimal repro?

Comment: sorry, "ihm" is "view in mvvm or human interface in french

Comment: I will publish detailed exception later at home but something crazy like "value not in range"

Comment: updated, please tell me if any idea...

Comment: i found a solution convert icon res to a datatemplte

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution, convert the viewbox to DataTemplate and bind to ContentTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BookIcon">
            <Viewbox Width="48" Height="48">
                <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                    <Path Data/>
                </Canvas>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{x:Bind Icon2}"/>
```

any other solution is welcome

Comment: `ContentTemplate` is looking for `DataTemplate` so what you did is absolutely correct.

Comment: sure, but i was looking for content binding